# sed Sanitize Muti-Line Substitution

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to accomplish the following task:

```
sed "s/{{HELP}}/$(dist/forge-cli.phar --no-ansi)/g" < post-build-hooks/readme.md.template > readme.md
```

The goal here is to take the results from `dist/forge-cli.phar`, which displays a help page for the command, and write it into my `readme.md` file. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
sed: 1: "s/{{HELP}}/Console Tool ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

The output from `dist/forge-cli.phar` contains multiple lines. The output is here:

```
Console Tool

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]

Options:
  --help           -h Display this help message.
  --quiet          -q Do not output any message.
  --verbose        -v|vv|vvv Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
  --version        -V Display this application version.
  --ansi              Force ANSI output.
  --no-ansi           Disable ANSI output.
  --no-interaction -n Do not ask any interactive question.

Available commands:
  cake             ??
  daemons          List the daemons configured by Forge
  env              Get a list of Environment Variables
  firewall         Get the public and private IPs for this server
  git              Displays details about a site's git repository.
  help             Displays help for a command
  ip               Get the public and private IPs for this server
  jobs             List the scheduled jobs configured by Forge
  keys             List the SSH Keys configured by Forge
  list             Lists commands
  monitoring       Describe Monitoring Services configured by Forge
  self-update      Update Forge CLI
  sites            List the sites configured by Forge
daemon
  daemon:restart   Restart a daemon
  daemon:status    Get the status of a daemon
log
  log:daemon       Get the latest log for a daemon
  log:deploy       Get the latest deploy log
  log:job          Get the latest log for a scheduled job
```

So here's the final question. How can I "sanitize" the output of my phar command to escape it properly for the sed command?

Comment: Is {{HELP}} on a line by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that {{HELP}} is on its own line in the file, you could do this using awk:

```
awk -v h="$(dist/forge-cli.phar --no-ansi)" '/{{HELP}}/{print h;next}1' in > out
```

When `/{{HELP}}/` is matched in the input file, print the contents of the variable `h` instead and skip to the next line. Otherwise, the `1` at the end just means that awk prints the line.

This only requires awk to be called once and prints the contents of `h` regardless of whether it contains any other characters that may be interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following command worked!

```
sed "s/{{HELP}}/$(dist/forge-cli.phar --no-ansi | gsed "s/$/\\\/g") /g" post-build-hooks/readme.md.template > readme.md
```

Comment: And what if the replacement string contains an `&` ?